# Borrow reputation from another member

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges

New users can't include images until they have not 10 points. Also SO has a lot of restrictions for comments, upvotes, downvotes and etc.

I think that users should be able to borrow points from another user, if another user likes.

So the new user can post an image and comment and etc.

Comment: There is a reason for these restrictions to be here. Allowing new users to borrow reputation from others (how, exactly?) would defeat that purpose. So far, the only way to transfer reputation is to offer a bounty, and even that is often abused by sockpuppets.

Comment: Many lf these restrictions are for people to learn the system.  I'm not sure we want to set up (what will actually be) a market in rep

Comment: Nope, get your own points and prove you're worthy of some of the privileges.

Answer (score 10):

## Reputation is trust

Ultimately reputation is an indication of how much the community trusts you, not that guy you owe a favour to. Allowing the unrestricted transfer of rep distorts this and reduced the meaningfulness of rep.

## Learning the system

The reason many things are based on rep is so that you gain access to tools once you have learned how they work (e.g. comments are not for answers). By skipping the initial learning phase you break this process and likely degrade the site quality.

## Side market in rep

By allowing free transfer of rep you are in significant danger of creating a market for rep. In this case people would buy and sell rep on a seperate site; rep becomes entirely meaningless and people will care only about gaining rep as quickly as possible to sell it, rather than caring about the community

## This specific case - images

In the case of images; just post a URL and someone will edit it in for you